# Error al hacer vagrant up "colision de red"

Tags: vagrant

Ejecutar `vagrant up` se presenta el siguiente error:

> The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network!

Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.1.100"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9042, host: 9042, guest_ip: "192.168.1.100"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9160, host: 9160, guest_ip: "192.168.1.100"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.memory = "3072"
     vb.cpus=1
   end
end
```

Traza del error completa:

> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>   ==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/xenial64'...
>   ==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
>   ==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/xenial64' is up to date...
>   ==> default: Setting the name of the VM: cassandraVM_default_1498184365715_32236
>   ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces... The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network! This will
>   cause your specified IP to be inaccessible. Please change the IP or
>   name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of a
>   bridged or non-hostonly network.

Answer (score 0):

El error se presenta por una colisión de red con la IP asignada al Anfitrion y la ip privada que se esta creando en el Invitado ([referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049717/vagrant-network-collides-with-a-non-hostonly-network?answertab=active#tab-top))

Pasos:

1. Verifique la ip de su sitema (`ipconfig`,`ifconfig`)
2. Modifique la ip en su archivo Vagrantfile ej:

   config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.2.100"
3. Inicie nuevamente el aprovisionamiento usando `vagrant up`